# Filtering out rows with NULL values only when a value already has a row with a NON NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 17.

I have a select statement with a group by that returns the following values. This is just a subset of 170k rows.

```
SELECT        child, parent
FROM            (SELECT child, parent
                          FROM table
                          GROUP BY child, parent) AS derivedtbl_1
ORDER BY child
```

| Child | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | NULL |
| 201 | 991 |
| 201 | 1020 |
| 202 | NULL |
| 203 | NULL |

I am struggling to find a select statement that filters out the first row. If a child already has a parent that is NOT NULL then I want it to filter out the row with the NULL value.

I have tried to solve it with a case when having count statement. For example if a value exists more than once in the child column then I want it to filter out the row where parent is NULL but all of my code so far returns errors.

| Child | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | 991 |
| 201 | 1020 |
| 202 | NULL |
| 203 | NULL |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT child, parent
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    Parent IS NOT NULL OR
    (Parent IS NULL AND
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                 WHERE t2.Child = t1.Child AND
                       t2.Parent IS NOT NULL));
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function for this. It may be faster or slower than using an `EXISTS` self-join, you need to test

```sql
SELECT
  child,
  parent
FROM (
    SELECT
      child,
      parent,
      AnyParent = MAX(parent) OVER (PARTITION BY child)
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY child, parent
) AS derivedtbl_1
WHERE AnyParent IS NOT NULL;
ORDER BY child
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello another way to filters out the first row if a child already has a parent that is NOT NULL could be this where we filtering in the where clause:

```
select child, parent
from your_table t
where case when parent is null and( 
select count(case when parent is null then 1 else 0 end)
from your_table 
where child=t.child 
 group by child
)>1 then 0 else 1 end =1
```

Hope it helps.